# How to increase the number of default rows in react-draft-wysig?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I need a WYSIWYG editor for my web application. For this purpose, I have started using react-draft-wysig. The whole editor displays correctly, but I would like to increase the default height of the text entry window.

This is how my editor looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZy1m.png

This is what the piece of code that defines my editor looks like:

```
const [editorState, onEditorStateChange ] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());

return(
...
<Editor editorState={editorState} onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange} editorClassName="editor-height"/>
```

The CSS class that was supposed to modify the default height of the text entry window:

```
.editor-height{
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The problem is that increasing the height increases the "background for the editor", while the text entry window does not change.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajCwj.png

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by adding the `editorStyle` prop, which allows you to add in-line styling. Then you can add a height or minHeight value.

```
<Editor editorStyle={{ height: '400px' }} />
```